# If a type of gunpowder is two and a third times more powerful than OTL gunpowder, what kinds of designs would be optimal?

Tags: weapons, alternate-history

I am currently trying to write an alternate history story. In the story a new type of gunpowder, called 'Greek sand' is developed by an alternate Roman Empire, using the secret recipe of Greek fire paired with gunpowder and sand to lower it's volatility. The powder is around 2.3 times as powerful as OTL gunpowder. My questions are:

- What types of alternate gun/bullet designs would have to be created(Focus is on penetration and range)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128166/discussion-on-question-by-sync-if-a-type-of-gunpowder-is-two-and-a-third-times-m).

Comment: Firearms and cannon have always been limited by the strength of the metal out of which they were made, not by the power of the propellant. In other words, they would use the same weapons as in real life just with less powder.

Comment: P.S. The power of pre-modern gunpowder varied by more than factor of 2 anyway -- the phrase "quality control" was invented in the 20th century. And the range of pre-modern weapons was limited by weapon design, not by muzzle velocity.

Comment: @AlexP: Not entirely true.  Problems can be caused by the speed at which a propellant burns.   Even though X grams of powder has the same power, the speed of delivery matters a great deal.  The classic case is reloading rifle cartridges with fast-burning pistol powder.

Comment: Greek fire seems an unlikely basis for such a substance. It's described as being a liquid incendiary, not an explosive, and some descriptions have it spontaneously igniting when exposed to water. Combining it with gunpowder would at best make gunpowder that fizzles when confined and tends to ignite if it gets damp...not really an improvement.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: But propellants are not explosives, they are chemicals which burn really fast, producing a lot of gas.  Ever burn some loose gunpowder?  It just burns quickly, unlike an explosive such as nitroglycerin.

Comment: @jamesqf most propellants are low explosives, and double-base and triple-base smokeless powders in fact incorporate nitroglycerin. It's not enough for them to burn quickly, they must burn in the absence of external sources of oxygen. Greek fire was just a blend of fuels and possibly some agent that produced heat on contact with water, it would have been useless as a propellant.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: My point was that gunpowder - either black powder or modern smokeless powders - does not explode unless confined.  It burns, quickly and without requiring oxygen from the air.  It's the comparatively slow buildup of pressure from that burning that pushes a bullet out of the barrel of a gun.  An explosive decomposes so quickly that it would shatter a normal barrel.

Comment: @jamesqf your claim is neither correct nor relevant. Black powder and smokeless powders *are* explosives (the whole reason the term "high explosive" exists is to distinguish such substances from low explosives like gunpowder), and Greek fire is not a propellant and would not increase the power of gunpowder.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: Sorry, but you're just wrong.  Gunpowder of any sort does not explode unless confined (try it!).  Guns work not by exploding their propellant, but by burning it to create gas pressure - that's why air rifles work.  And I said nothing about Greek fire: lIRC no one even knows what that actually was.

Comment: @jamesqf for the last time, gunpowder is a *low explosive*. Low explosives generally *don't* explode unless confined (though some can become self-confining or progress to detonation in the right conditions), but they *do* explode when confined, **which is why they're considered explosives**. In fact, for most of the history of explosives, low-explosive materials such as black powder were the *only* useful explosives. This is hardly esoteric or controversial, it'll be immediately evident to anyone willing to do a bit of research that you're wrong. Quit making a fool of yourself.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: You're entirely missing the point.  Yes, AS I WROTE, you can make gunpowder explode if you confine it.  But its use in firearms (and things like rockets) depends on it NOT exploding, but burning at a fast but controlled rate in order to act as a propellant.  Indeed, if you confine it within a gun, you often get an explosion.  (See "barrel obstruction burst.)  And if you want to see a fool, try a mirror :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens when you increase the power of gunpowder?

[image]

[image]

Unless they can also make gun barrels equally stronger, the extra power of the Greek sand will turn your gun into a handheld pipe bomb.

#### So you'll immediately use 2.3 times less than we do obviously.

However this isn't the end of the story. **A mistake while mixing has 2.3 times the unintended consequences as it does in our timeline.**

Gun barrels will need to be thicker on early firearms (while they're learning how to mix it constantly there needs to be more safety margin, as a few gram error is more of a problem), this will make them heavier and harder to aim without a support. Stands and shoulder straps will be more common.

After some centuries I expect manufacturing the gunpowder consistency to get to the point where small and light guns resembling ours start to exist. Bullets will have less powder that our universe, but the average gun and round will be essentially indistinguishable from what we have.

#### The differences will be in what precision manufactured bullets can do.

What will be different is specialised rounds. Incendary rounds can burn for longer after impact, starting fires more reliably. Tracers can burn for longer, giving longer paths. Armour peircing rounds can be slightly  more penetrating. Flare rounds can last for longer and be brighter. Hollywood rounds will make a brighter muzzle flash.

Where the difference may be more notable is rounds that detonate on impact. You have extra gunpowder strength and extra room in the projectile for more powder for the secondary explosion.

Also worth considering is a round that's fused to detonate n meters after firing. If you have someone hiding behind cover, use a machine gun to spray bullets above them, these bullets detonate above them, sending buckshot or similar mini projectiles all directions, including into those hiding behind cover. You've just fired around a corner.

Comment: You have exactly that problem with e.g. British bespoke shotguns.  New ones START in the neighborhood of £100K, and go up from there: https://www.thefield.co.uk/shooting/most-expensive-guns-26087  That means that older guns from the era of black powder are still used, and valued.  However, if you use modern, more powerful smokeless power cartridges in them, the barrels can burst.  You also get similar problems when using fast-burning pistol powders in rifles.

Comment: Are you assuming that they just shove in as much gunpowder as they can instead of just using less? Past the first few exploding guns, they would just learn to use 2-3 times less than we do now to the same effect, ignoring the accidents that's always happened with early gunpowder. I doubt the design of early guns would change much as there's only so many ways you can shape a barrel and plug it with a projectile. In those days, it was a loong barrel to help accuracy, and as much powder as was safe (less in this case)

Comment: In reality firearms and cannon are limited by the strength of the material of the barrel, not by the power of the propellant; and a factor of 2 is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: However, imagine how more powerful a grenade with this gunpowder could be.

Comment: @HenryShao yes as I point out they'll use 2.3 times less. But That still has consequences on barrel design while they're fine tuning gunpowder manufacturer.